# TypeScript class property lookup method type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics, static-typing

I am struggling to get type inference to work with class property lookup.

What I want:

```
class Family <T extends { [name: string]: Animal }> {
  public members: T

  public lookup <K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K] {
    return this.members[name]
  }
}

class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

const cat = new Cat
const dog = new Dog

const foo = new Family
foo.members = { kitty: cat, bob: dog }
const result1 = foo.lookup('missing') // I want this to fail for missing key. It doesn't.
const result2 = foo.lookup('kitty') // I want this has inferred type Cat. It doesn't.
```

I believe above is achievable as I got the function version working as below

```js
function lookup <O, K extends keyof O> (obj: O, key: K): O[K] {
  return obj[key]
}

const o = { a:1, b: 'text'}
const r = lookup(o, 'a') // correctly inferred type number
const r2 = lookup(o, 'b') // correctly inferred type string
```

Any help or guideline will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a variable is generally inferred when the variable is declared, and generally does not change after (so `foo` is typed as `Family<{ [name: string]: Animal; >` since at the time of initialization there is no other information available)

If you can pass `member` to the constructor, to have `T` inferred based on the argument that will work as expected:

```
class Family <T extends { [name: string]: Animal }> {
  constructor(public members: T) { }

  public lookup <K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K] {
    return this.members[name]
  }
}

const result1 = foo.lookup('missing') // err
const result2 = foo.lookup('kitty') // cat
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=43&pln=16&pc=49#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiYFsCWICe0A8AVaBTAHgC64B2AJjAN7QDaJiuAXNBIQE5IkDmAuswIIkkCMCGgBfAHzRKAWABQ0aMAD2JVmwCuwQirYAKAA6aARiCTBoCXAhO42EZlgCUMiQoVLjZi9BAqVAGtNQ0wAaTwiUgpoQNxUFQAzaCxJfXprZjDnJxownhlPJWg2XEJNNhJoQgALJAgAOmtbewg6Bh4i8QVu+QVQSBhBYVEZXoGoaABhMEJI4nIhoRExSnHwSYARFS556KWR1d7+tVZlWegAXmgSXAB3admT9TmyHaub++htrg95VRe0ESAQ+twe8GQaH01ECSEIhFQzGAswANNATCoTMw3rtxM5nmdShBNCBCABGD7AlQNfxBEL6ADkyCgnC4DNcAHoOXg2GwCXMiSTCAAmSkBGkBYKGRmw+GodnQLnnQgKIA)

Specifying the type argument explicitly to the constructor is also an option, but not as convenient:

```
const foo = new Family<{ kitty: Cat, bob: Dog }>()
foo.members = { kitty: cat, bob: dog }
const result1 = foo.lookup('missing') // err
const result2 = foo.lookup('kitty') // cat
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiYFsCWICe0A8AVaBTAHgC64B2AJjAN7QDaJiuAXNBIQE5IkDmAuswIIkkCMCGgBfAHzRKAWABQ0aAAcArgCMQSYNAS4E63GwjMsAbgUKlazduggA9g4DWq5ZgDSeIqQrRnuKgOAGbQWJIAFPR6zB4AlKY0HjwyVkrQbLiEqmwk0IQAFkgQAHR6BkYQdAw8aeIK9fIKoJAwgsKiMo0tUNAAwmCE3sTkbUIiYpTd4L0AIg5cw75jHZONzQ4krNDAg9AAvNAkuADu-YMbW0NkCwdHp9DzXJbywJvbwU53x2fwyGgYajOJCEQioZgDQgAGmg6gc6mYTwkkTiCk+DjK+kMxjuQJBYOYu2hsPhzBui267yGmQgqhAhAAjHd0SVHC43BEAOTIKCcLicuLQAD0QrwbDYl22NLphAATMynKynK5lFzgaDUALhaKiQogA)

Now if neither of these options is not feasible, you could go a more esoteric route, and use a [custom assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). These custom assertions if used as a the top level statement can change the type of a variable:

```
class Family <T extends { [name: string]: Animal }> {
  private members!: T;
  public setMemebers<TNew extends T>(members: TNew): asserts this is Family<TNew> {
    this.members = members;
  }

  public lookup <K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K] {
    return this.members[name]
  }
}

class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

const cat = new Cat
const dog = new Dog

const foo: Family<any> = new Family()
foo.setMemebers({ kitty: cat, bob: dog });
const result1 = foo.lookup('missing') // err
const result2 = foo.lookup('kitty') // cat
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiYFsCWICe0A8AVaBTAHgC64B2AJjAN7QDaJiuAXNBIQE5IkDmAuswIIkkCMCGgBfAHzRKAWABQ0aAAcOANzDFoCXAgBGuNhACEzLAG4FS5QFc9IJMBa5CAWV24DR7ADlcAdzwiUgpoLEkACh19QwgzP38ASmZICENCGEIACyQYXLhEFFRfAOk5RSVobNyAOmivGABebV0GywrxBSsVOwcnEAB7AYBrG2VMAGkg4nIYYdxUAYAzMMj6HWYJ5LCaCZ4ZbqU2Fxs2EiqciDrW2LoGHm7O+SeFUFToQWFRGSe3qGgAMKaaYhGCfERiSi-cD-AAiAy4INmHyEEJ+XXkwAGJFY0GAwOaJACgM0r2xuLICOghOJ8K4GKxOMI0CWQ2Y8GQaAwYBIqGkNMCHKKEUSClZAxqaTcHgaEWowyQhEIqGY+MIABpoHoBnpmJTEeJEu1GbjjhAbCBCABGaksoY1QYjMYRADkyCgnC4LsS0AA9L68Gw2GSmdAzRbCAAmW3ih1DUbKV0KpWob1+gNqhRAA)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome detailed answer. Option 3 is an eye-opener. 
My original plan was to have method `addMember(name: string, member: Animal)` and then iteratively add new items. But base on your explanation, the type inference magic only happen at the non-mutating definition time, so `addMember` will not support the later lookup type inference. Am I right?

Comment: @IvanWang yes that is mostly right, unless `addMember` is a custom type assertion, but generally no, a later call to a member does not change the type of the object